# TFS 2013 Build Service connect to TFS2012 server

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

I have TFS2012 Update 3 server. We have started new VS 2013 project. I need to prepare build server and service. My initial thought is to install Vs 2013 together with TFS2013 build service.
After installation TFS2013 and registration to TFS collection I got below issue:

The register command is not supported for Team Foundation Service [our_tfs_url] because the server is not compatible.

Please advice any solution how to create builds for VS 2013 projects that are stored in TFS 2012.

**Update 1:**

1) I installed TFS 2012 build service and redirect msbuild  ( toolpath) in build template to use VS 2013 msbuild

2) I am able now to build project with a test

3) **There are still issue with Code Coverage, that finish with warning:  Install visual studio.  It seems for me that CC used still VS 2012. Is any way to redirect CC to VS 2013?**

Comment: The only way I know how is to install VS2013 on the build server and then alter the tool path in the Build XAML. The updates you provide indicate that you are on the correct path. You can also try enforcing version by adding /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0 to the MSBuild command

Comment: Thansk, you right. I did that settigns in clone of default template and I am able to build over vs 2013 msbuild.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution helps me build on VS 2013 build machine with TFS 2012 build service and generate code coverage.

TFS 2012 buid service runs tests from 11.0 location, to replace CommonExtensions in folder

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions

with Vs 2013 assemblies from

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions

fix that issue and now I can see code coverage per build.

thanks MS to provide workaround on that issue with Code coverage.